# Sqlmap tool in a web application

Tags: python, sql, security, sql-injection, sqlmap

My web app takes a url of a website as input and then checks if that website is protected from SQL injection attack or if it's vulnerable.

My problem here, can I use the sqlmap tool to help me in the process of the detection? BTW I'm using Flask (Python) in the backend.

But in the process of utilizing the sqlmap tool, I tried to read the output and then parse the JSON output of SQLMap. But I don't have a clear idea of how I can start integrating it into my web app.

Comment: So, what is your actual question?

Comment: my question here, can i use sqlmap as a tool for my web app so i can detect the vulnerability of a website, let's say more easily ? and how and where exactly should i integrate it ? and should i transform the output's format from csv to json so the data can be sent normaly ?

Comment: So... you want to run an automated hacking website?

Comment: no that's not the main goal of it or maybe kinda idk i'm just a newbie in the dev world. the web app meant to display a message, if the website is protected or not, i can extract a specific things from the output of sqlmap to know if it's injectable or not. no need to hack, just if the sqli's 'specific type' works on that website then return a response. so it's just a test, and it is a local project. is it possible to do this or not ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.